# Assembly Language- Exception Thrown error

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, runtime-error, masm

I just started taking a class in assembly language and we had our first project in class and I just can't seem to understand what is wrong with this code. I have tried everything from the book but to no avail

```
include C:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc

.data
;Variables are listed in following order VAR DATATYPE DIGITS[RADIX] with 
comments showing binary version of listed digits
left DWORD 321                                      ;101000001b
right DWORD 4247                                    ;1000010010111b 
total DWORD ?                                   ;uninitialized
diff DWORD ?                                    ;uninitialized

;Calculate length of Array and move to var ArrayLength
Array WORD 1,2,4,8,16,32,64                         ;Array 
ArrayLength = ($ - Array) / 2

.code
main PROC

;Move left and right to respective registers
MOV eax,left
MOV ebx,right

;Add left var and right var and store in new var called total and move to 
ecx

MOV total,eax
ADD total,ebx
MOV ecx,total

;Subtract left var and right var and store in new var called diff and move 
to edx  

MOV diff,eax
SUB diff,ebx
MOV edx,diff

;Define a string called message containing HELLO WORLD!
message BYTE '"Hello world!"'

;Move Array to esi
MOV esi,ArrayLength

CALL DumpRegs

exit

main ENDP
END main
```

When I try to run it I get

> Exception thrown at 0x002A368D in ASM_Proj1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000001A6.

At line 36 which is `MOV edx,diff`

Any ideas what could be going on?
*For the record I am using Visual Studio 2017*

Comment: total is DWORD type is a leftover from the good old days of 16-bit. or you try to add 32 bit (eax) you can ax (16bits) but no eax, regards.

Comment: Your error is unlikely to be that line. It's more likely it's because you put your `message` in the middle of code. Move that to the data section.

Comment: Check the assembly listing, or in VS2017 the disassembly view, how the message bytes (first is `'H' = 0x48`) are treated as instruction (and executed after `mov edx,diff`). Also you can use the VS debugger to step over single instruction, so you will see the `mov edx,diff` is not a problem.

Comment: And why do you subtract 4247 from 321 and not vice versa?
I mean, perhaps, you'd better `MOV diff,ebx` and then `SUB diff,eax`. Huh?
Also, you perform `CALL` in the end, but we don't see any listing for that subprogram.

Comment: @Jester Thank you for that it did cancel out the error message and I am not getting an error message anymore but it still wont display the register contents

Comment: @BronislavElizavetin It was an assignment and I was asked to do it in this order. I believe the CALL DumpRegs calls the subprogram found in the Irvine32.inc file

Comment: Yes, indeed, probably in that *.inc* file. But don't you want to show its contents or at least that particular subprogram code?